# Speeding Up, Joining and Increasing Frame Rate FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

["Is it possible to speed up a video using handbrake?"](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18469/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-a-video-using-handbrake)

In the above link, Mulvya show us how to speed up a video, but I want to know, if possible, how can I speed the video joining two or more videos and increasing the frame rate, for example:

I have 2 video files, which I need to join. Both are at 30fps and I want to speed up to 5 times and increase the frame rate to 60fps.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming audio's not a concern,

```
ffmpeg -i in1.mov -i in2.mov -filter_complex
       "[0]setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/5[a];[1]setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/5[b];[a][b]concat[v]"
       -map "[v]" -r 60 -crf 18 output.mov
```